# Stored Procedure for updating multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, gridview, edit

I'm trying to display multiple tables' data from SQL Server to a GridView and allow users to edit the rows. Currently, I am able to display data & allow users to click on **Edit** link in GridView to modify row.

But once I clicked on Update, the row **remains the same**. The changes I've made are not updated.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatetable2
    (@Atd_ID INT,
     @Atd_Date DATE,
     @Atd_InTime TIME(7),
     @Atd_OutTime TIME(7),
     @Atd_Comment VARCHAR(50),
     @Status VARCHAR(50),
     @SID INT,
     @S_FName VARCHAR(50),
     @S_LName VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE attendance 
    SET Atd_Date = @Atd_Date, 
        Atd_InTime = @Atd_InTime, 
        Atd_OutTime = @Atd_OutTime, 
        Atd_Comment = @Atd_Comment, 
        Status = @Status 
     WHERE Atd_ID = @Atd_ID

     UPDATE student 
     SET S_FName = @S_FName, 
         S_LName = @S_LName 
     WHERE SID = @SID
END
RETURN
```

Is there something wrong in my stored procedure?

This is my `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SAOS1ConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT attendance.Atd_Date, attendance.Atd_InTime, attendance.Atd_OutTime, attendance.Atd_Comment, attendance.Status, attendance.SID, student.S_FName, student.S_LName FROM attendance INNER JOIN student ON attendance.SID = student.SID INNER JOIN class ON student.CID = class.CID WHERE (class.CID = @CID) AND (attendance.Atd_Date = @Atd_Date)" 
     UpdateCommand="updatetable2" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
       <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LabelClassID" Name="CID" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="datepicker" Name="Atd_Date" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Atd_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Atd_Date" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Time" Name="Atd_InTime" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Time" Name="Atd_OutTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Atd_Comment" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="S_FName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="S_LName" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: SP is almost fine except: no transaction, `return` (which is redundant here) is after `end`. None of this has anything to do with "remains the same". Continue debugging.

Comment: @IvanStarostin What do you mean no transaction. Should I remove `return`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Do I need to write code for event handler to update rows in C#?

Comment: Each statement within the stored proc will execute in an independent transaction (unless a transaction is started on the client) so, if the first update succeeds and the second fails (or visa-versa), you would end up with inconsistent data,

Comment: Please show `EditTemplate` of your `GridView`.